# position: sticky stops half way?

Tags: css

I have a sidebar that has the  `position: sticky` added to it, but when I scroll past a certain point it stops being sticky?!

*Tested in Chrome version: Version 61.0.3163.100 and Safari Version: 11.0*

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sticky">
  this should stick!
</div>

<div class="content">
  this is content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style media="screen">
  .sticky {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: -moz-sticky;
    position: -ms-sticky;
    position: -o-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
  }

  .content{
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 3000px;
    width: 700px;
    float: right;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: It's an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: sticky;` is not supported most of browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky

You can try something like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="sticky-block">
  this should stick!
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.sticky {
   position: fixed;
   top: 15px;
}
```

**JS**:

```
var $stickyBlock = document.querySelector('.sticky-block');
var origOffsetY = $stickyBlock.offsetTop - 15; // 15 is your top margin

function onScroll() {
    window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? $stickyBlock.classList.add('sticky') :
    $stickyBlock.classList.remove('sticky');
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
```

or **jQuery**:

```
var $stickyBlock = $('.sticky-block');
var origOffsetY = $stickyBlock.offset().top - 15;  // 15 is your top margin

function onScroll() {
    window.scrollY >= origOffsetY ? $stickyBlock.addClass('sticky') :
    $stickyBlock.removeClass('sticky');
}

$(document).on('scroll', onScroll);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xixe/ka0h4097/)

Comment: Thanks for the code example, I was looking for a pure way of doing this with CSS but see it's not stable at the moment. Your code is perfect, only think now is the sidebar overflows into the footer when I reach the end. God I hate sticky/fixed elements....

Comment: You also can use jQuery plugins http://stickyjs.com/ or http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/

Comment: `Position:sticky` is supported quite well by now and I have this problem too. The first column in a fake table with flexboxes sticks to the left while scrolling horizontally. When scrolling further than one viewport width, the first (sticky) column disappears to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Here, try this, I would say it's better for this rather than using "Sticky" and it doesn't use Jquery or anything just simple position fixed.

Html

```
<div class="sticky">
  this should stick!
</div>

<div class="content">
  this is content
</div>
```

Css

```
.sticky {
    background-color: #ccc;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    position:fixed;
  }

  .content{
    background-color: #eee;
    height: 3000px;
    width: 700px;
    float: right;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udxuh1qf/

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code on jsfiddle and also here, it is probably your screen media query that causes your problem. Check out my version of sticky. I hope it will fix your issue.

```css
      .sticky {
      background-color: #ccc;
      color:red;
      position: sticky;/* required */
      position: -webkit-sticky;/* required */
      top: 15px; /* required */
      float:left;
      }

      .content{
        background-color: #eee;
        height: 3000px;
        width: 700px;
        float right;
      }
```

```html
    <div class="sticky">
      this should stick!
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      this is content
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle and I think the sticky element is still buggy for production, I wanted to avoid a JS implementation but I tried the code example above and works.